# Does deleting a collection in the firebase/firestore console delete all sub collections?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

I am aware of how to delete sub collections when a parent collection is deleted programmatically however I can't find any documentation on what happens when you delete a parent collection from the console manually.

Follow up question:

Is there a way to check for undeleted sub collections?
I assume these use up storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested what happens in the Firebase console when you delete a collection, and it shows this dialog:

[image]

So it looks like deleting a collection in the console also deletes any subcollections under it.